# D3 - Binding CSV Data to Array

Tags: csv, d3.js, data-binding

Good morning,

Apologies for what is going to be a simple question and will undoubtedly show my complete lack of understanding on the subject though I have been playing around for hours trying to understand this though clearly I am missing something quite fundamental.

I have a CSV file that I have successfully loaded:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

It contains 28 rows of data, with 4 columns.

I am trying to "bind" the data to 3 separate arrays dependent on the column...

```
var Array1 = [],
        Array2 = [],
        Array3 = []

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      Array1.push([ i, 10]);
      Array2.push([ i, 20]);
      Array3.push([ i, 30]);
    }
```

The above code works but isn't linked to the data set... what I really want is shown below where the caps marks the data in the CSV file:

```
var Array1= [],
        Array2 = [],
        Array3 = []

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      Array1.push([ FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN]);
      Array2.push([ FIRSTCOLUMN, THIRDCOLUMN]);
      Array3.push([ FIRSTCOLUMN, FOURTHCOLUMN]);
    }
```

Sorry, I realise this is a really stupid question... but perhaps just a link to an article to explain what I need would really help?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to explain your desired outcome better, because what you have in your question is not an simple array, but an array of arrays. If you need an array of objects, where each object has the value of column 1 and any other given column, please update your question.

For building a simple array based on your data, you can use `map`.

So, suppose this is your CSV:

```
firstColumn,secondColumn,thirdColumn,fourthColumn
12,3,44,35
15,32,17,42
//...
```

For building an array with the values of the second column, for instance, write:

```
var myArray = data.map(function(d){
    return d.secondColumn;
});
```

Inside your callback (`function(data){...`).

**EDIT:** Based on the comments, this is what you want:

Given your data array, you have to access each object by index and selecting the corresponding column by key. So, to access the values in your first column:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    newArray.push([i, myData[i].firstColumn])
};
```

Do the same for the other columns. This is a working demo:

```js
var myData = [{firstColumn: 4, secondColumn: 12, thirdColumn: 21, forthColumn: 11},
{firstColumn: 41, secondColumn: 22, thirdColumn: 71, forthColumn: 10},
{firstColumn: 10, secondColumn: 16, thirdColumn: 2, forthColumn: 15},
{firstColumn: 6, secondColumn: 32, thirdColumn: 7, forthColumn: 17},
{firstColumn: 33, secondColumn: 12, thirdColumn: 29, forthColumn: 19}];

var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
newArray.push([i, myData[i].firstColumn])
};

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response my friend. I am actually trying to alter the code in the really cool line chart at the following location: http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069 ... the bottom section of the code enters the data, though it currently uses random numbers. I'm simply trying to replace this with my own data. I'm sure it's something really easy to do though I'm jumping in the deep end as I have never used Javascript or D3 before, though I do have working knowledge of .net

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, I now have it working. It was actually the simple part of referring to the column name that was causing me so much confusion (myData[i].firstColumn) - I knew how to refer to the data though not to a particular column - I must have spent hours googling trying to find out how to do that one part. I have learnt a lot from your help

Comment: @AdrianGreenwood  Since this is your first question at Stackoverflow, let me give you a tip: if the answer is useful, accept/upvote it (the buttons and the green tick at the top left).

Comment: I did upvote it though was advised it won't be displayed publicly as I have a low reputation. I have ticked it now, which was an option I didn't see yesterday

Comment: This is strange, there is indeed a time limit for accepting the answer, but only minutes... Anyway, I'm happy you have a working code now. Cheers.